# Export IList<T> Data Nested Within Other IList<obj> by using EPPlus, having Feature of Collapse

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel, epplus, nopcommerce

Currently I´m working with a feature for exporting some data from ILIST object having nested IList.

Goal of this is to achieve is a collapsible Excel [with EPPlus] where the 1. first row have Product columns values 2. after it's attribute in second row.

Then after again "Product Columns values" and after that it's Attributes.

[See Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCskF.png)

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                using (var xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream))
                {

                    // get handles to the worksheets
                    var worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(typeof(Product).Name);
                    var fpWorksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DataForProductsFilters");
                    fpWorksheet.Hidden = eWorkSheetHidden.VeryHidden;
                    var fbaWorksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DataForProductAttributesFilters");
                    fbaWorksheet.Hidden = eWorkSheetHidden.VeryHidden;
                    var fsaWorksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DataForSpecificationAttributesFilters");
                    fsaWorksheet.Hidden = eWorkSheetHidden.VeryHidden;


                    // optional feature for loading all data from list variable
                    worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(itemsToExport, true, TableStyles.Medium15);

                    //create Headers and format them 
                    var manager = new PropertyManager<Product>(properties.Where(p => !p.Ignore));
                    manager.WriteCaption(worksheet, SetCaptionStyle);


                    // Loop through All the IList<Product> and It's Attributes.
                    // This taking too much time (ex.20 min). 

                    var row = 2;
                    foreach (var item in itemsToExport)
                    {
                        manager.CurrentObject = item;
                        manager.WriteToXlsx(worksheet, row++, _catalogSettings.ExportImportUseDropdownlistsForAssociatedEntities, fWorksheet: fpWorksheet);

                        if (_catalogSettings.ExportImportProductAttributes)
                        {
                            row = ExportProductAttributes(item, productAttributeManager, worksheet, row, fbaWorksheet);
                        }

                        if (_catalogSettings.ExportImportProductSpecificationAttributes)
                        {
                            row = ExportSpecificationAttributes(item, specificationAttributeManager, worksheet, row, fsaWorksheet);
                        }
                    }
                    xlPackage.Save();
                }
```

Comment: Great. What is your question?

Comment: Hello Stephen,
Is there any way with that we can create collapsible Excel with It's Attribute.
Ex.  Product  in First Row  After That It's Attributes.
With EPPlus.

Please check Image you will get more, what I want to achieve.